# Set date picker value equals null, in liferay alloy ui

Tags: javascript, liferay, alloy-ui

i'm creating a date picker in liferay alloy-ui. This code displays as default the date at this moment, but i want to set it null, cause i want that the user sets it. i tried to not display the date as input ,but the value of it, didn't change. Below is my code. Can anyone help me? thank you in advance.

```
div class="aui-datepicker aui-helper-clearfix" id="#<portlet:namespace/>beginDatePicker">
    <input type="text" name="beginDate" id="<portlet:namespace/>beginDate" size="30" value=""/>
</div>


<aui:script>
    AUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(A) {
      var simpleDatepicker1 = new A.DatePicker({
       trigger: '#<portlet:namespace />beginDate',
        }).render('##<portlet:namespace />beginDatePicker');
     });
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use JSP. In this case I would use following liferay taglib tags:

```
<aui:field-wrapper name="beginDate" label="myBeginDate">
    <liferay-ui:input-date nullable="true" name="beginDate" dayParam="beginDateDay" monthParam="beginDateMonth" yearParam="beginDateYear"/>
</aui:field-wrapper>
```

`AUI` tag is used to provide compatibility with aui forms (layouting of label etc.). `liferay-ui:input-date` is used because aui don't define any date entry tag. **`nullable`** attribute delivers specifically what you need.

This will add following params to you request (if you use regular submit):

- beginDateDay
- beginDateMonth
- beginDateYear

You can use them in your controller or jsp page to create date:

```
int day = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "beginDateDay");
...
Date entryDate = PortalUtil.getDate(beginDateMonth, beginDateDay, ebeginDateYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<aui:input id="beginDate" name="beginDate" class="form-control" type="text"  label="Begin Date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" autocomplete="off" />

<aui:script>
var beginDatepicker = new Y.DatePicker({
        trigger : '#<portlet:namespace/>beginDate',
        mask : '%m/%d/%Y',
        popover : {
            zIndex : 1
        }
    });
</aui:script>
```

By default, you will get the placeholder "MM/dd/yyyy" in the date field, unless user enters or sets a date.

HTH